# error with time data does not match format

Tags: python-3.x

[I am having this data and try to convert the string date to datetime format. and I have this time data does not match format error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFn2y.png)

```
    Date=stock['Trddt'].values
    datetime.datetime.strptime(Date[0], "%y.%m.%d")
```

and it return this error:
ValueError: time data '2015/11/23' does not match format '%y.%m.%d'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please supply a **[mcve]**. This means no images/links, just text.

Answer (score 0):

Try `datetime.datetime.strptime(Date[0], "%Y/%m/%d")`.

`%y` matches years without century, but you have years with century, so you need capital `%Y`.